# Codeigniter database result instance class location and class name

Tags: codeigniter

I recently learned that you can provide a class name to the `Query->result()` and it will use that to instantiate the results, rather then using plain `stdClass`. [more here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#content)

My first attempt was to the in `application/models/classes` and name them the same as the model, but without the `_model` suffix. So I would have a `Posts_model` that returns instances of `Post` from the database. But the problem is that I also have a Controller named `Post` and obviously PHP throws a Fatal Error.

*So the question is*:  Is there is a convention as to where to put this classes and how to name them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Codeigniter goes, there are no convetions, and the built-in loader is kinda ill-suited for only including files and not instantiate them. I would recommend to integrate some [psr-0 compatibile autoloader.](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

As of most mvc web frameworks, they usually uses the plural form for the controllers and singular for models. For example: `Users` is a controller and `User` is the modell.

Comment: Thanks, I really hoped there was a convetion. At least for now I renamed my conflicting controller name and I can use the single form for the "instanciation class".